# Is there a quick way to clear a customvalidator as soon as the fields been changed?

Tags: c#, .net, customvalidator

I have a custom validator that uses server side validation.

I also have a bunch of client side required field validators and these clear as soon as something is entered in them.

I was wondering is there some sort of attribute that clears the custom validator as soon as I edit the field?

Comment: without. i simply want to clear it - as it looks inconsistent. I'll validate it again when they hit submit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That should work ..

1- Write a client side validation status reset function:

```
function CustomValidator_ClientValidation(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid= true;
}
```

2- Set the ClientValidationFunction of your CustomValidator to that function:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
    ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator_ClientValidation" .... >
```

3- Remember to assign the name of your field to the ControlToValidate property..